# Suggest that the browser wrap text earlier?

Tags: html, css

So, I have a `<p>` element with some text inside and `text-align: center`. If the text overfills the given width, it begins to wrap to the next line. This sometimes leaves a single word hanging at the bottom. Is there a way to get the browser to try to split the lines evenly in half if a wrap is necessary?

Comment: You could try using `text-align: justify` to see if that renders more like what you want. Other than that you will need to use javascript to format the string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a no-break space instead of a normal space before the last two words, or in general between any consecutive words that should appear on the same line. E.g.,

```
<p>This does <em>not</em> leave a single word hanging at the&nbsp;bottom.</p>
```